# vectorize head(which(t > x), n=1) for many values of x

Tags: r

I have a situation similar to the following in R:

```
t <- (1:100) * 15
x <- c(134, 552, 864, 5000)
```

And I want to find for each value in x what the first index in t where t > x is. The following works using a loop:

```
y <- numeric(length(x))
for (i in 1:length(x))
    y[i] <- which(t > x[i])[1]

# y
# [1]  9 37 58 NA
```

I was taught that loops in R are 'bad and slow', and while the time this takes to run for a reasonably large x is not a deal-breaker, I would like to know whether there is a better way?

Comment: Loops on R are not "bad and slow". Since you pre-allocate the object, which you fill with the loop, the loop is perfectly fine.

Comment: So the main overhead in loops would be from re-allocating objects that change size, rather than something inherent in processing the loop (boundary checking and such...)?

Comment: Yes. The `for` loops themselves are actually pretty efficient. Beginners often use very inefficient code (like growing an object) inside the loop and that let to the misconception that loops are slow. Of course, truly vectorized functions (which does not include `*apply` functions) are pretty much always faster than a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun <- function(x){
    which(t > x)[1]
}

R > sapply(x, fun)
[1]  9 37 58 NA
```

Comment: No need to define a named function for that. ;-)

Comment: Ah. I was trying to make `apply` work for this and not getting anywhere.

Comment: Or use `which.max` and drop the `[1]`

Answer (score 2):

If the objects are not too big (so that RAM is not limiting), you don't need `*apply` functions, which are just hidden loops.

```
temp <- outer(x,t,'<')
y <- length(t) - (rowSums(temp)-1)
y[y>length(t)] <- NA
#[1]  9 37 58 NA
```

Comment: I quite like this one, but `temp` does get very large.

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same:

```
require(functional)
apply(matrix(t > rep(x, each=length(t)), length(t)), 2, Compose(which, Curry(append, Inf), min))
## [1]   9  37  58 Inf
```